# Where's $\dfrac{\sinh(\sin z)}{z^2+9}$ analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-riemann-equations

The exercise pretty much asks to find the domain on which the function above,
$$f(z)=\dfrac{\sinh(\sin z)}{z^2+9},$$
is analytic.

The numerator, $\sinh(\sin z)$, is an entire function so we shall only care about the denominator: we should impose $z^2+9\neq 0\iff z\neq\pm 3i$. Still, I'm pretty lost on how this relates to the domain of analycity since in the solutions they talk about singularities at $z=\pm i$ (most likely a typo?). Finally, does Cauchy-Riemann conditions intervene here? Would that provide some more information about the domain we want to find?

Comment: It is a typo. Using the Cauchy-Riemann to prove the  function is analytic in its domain would be, in theory, possible, but the sensible way to prove it would be to use the theorems about composition, sum, quotients, ... of analytic functions.

Comment: Then it suffices by arguing its analicity with what I said in the first two lines. Cauchy-Riemann would be clearly cumbersome in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right. The only singularities are at $z = \pm 3i$, since a quotient of analytic functions is analytic unless the denominator vanishes.

The Cauchy-Riemann equations don't give any additional information here:

- Away from the singularities, you've already noticed that there's a more convenient way to see that the function is analytic; no need to go through the trouble of calculating the real and imaginary parts.
- At the singularities, the partial derivatives in the Cauchy-Riemann equations don't even exist, so the equations fail in a trivial way.

(The Cauchy-Riemann equations are only "interesting" when you have a function $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ that's already real-differentiable at a point, and you're wondering if it's *also* complex-differentiable there. If the function is not even real-differentiable, there's nothing to check.)

Comment: Thank you! All's much clearer now.